# Overwrite a database

Tags: python, database, mysql-python, overwrite

I have an online database and connect to it by using MySQLdb.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(......)
cur = db.cursor() 
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME")
data = cur.fetchall()
```

Now, I want to write the whole database to my localhost (overwrite). Is there any way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Take your data, pack it into an sql (insert) statement, connect to your local DB and insert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading you correctly, you have two database servers, A and B (where A is a remote server and B is running on your local machine) and you want to copy a database from server A to server B?

In all honesty, if this is a one-off, consider using the mysqldump command-line tool, either directly or calling it from python.

If not, the last answer on http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/24635-dump-table-data-mysqldb details the SQL needed to define a procedure to output tables and data, though this may well miss subtleties mysqldump does not